# Moving local repo to a new Macbook

Tags: git, github

I have seen some information on this topic, but didn't see a definitive agreement on the proper strategy.

I just got a new macbook and have been setting everything up over the past few days.  I have a git repo on the old machine that I want to move over to the new machine, what is the best way for me to move the entire folder over to the new machine (note - I will no longer be using the old machine).

Answer (score 1):

As git is **decentralized** (which actually means [**distributed**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control#Distributed-Version-Control-Systems)), you can safely copy your original clone entire folder (the one with the `.git` sub-directory) from your old machine to the new one without losing anything. Even your local commits or branches will be kept as git embeds the complete distant AND local history in each clone.

---

**Direct answer to your question**

Just make a hard copy of your original clone and test a git command on your new one:

```
# assuming you're actually on your new machine:
scp -r old-user@old-machine:/old/path/ /new/path/
cd /new/path/
# check that GIT still consider your directory as a clone
git status
# test if your remotes are still valid
git remote update
```

The only point to take care of is to embed the `.git` sub-directory with your copy (which may be hidden on OSX by default).

EDIT - You could even make a tarball of the original clone and extract it on your new machine (just be sure to embed the .git sub-directory contents).

---

**To go a little further**

You could even make a true `git clone` of your original old machine directory and have the exact same result (except any uncommitted change). This is the real meaning of a *distributed* VCS:

```
git clone old-user@old-machine:/old/path/ /new/path/
```